# Save and after restore the scroll position is just slighlty off

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, scrollview

I am saving my `NestedScrollView` state like this

```
void initListeners(){
    scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener((NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener) (v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY) -> saveScrollPosition(scrollX,scrollY));
}

void saveScrollPosition(int x, int y) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putInt(SCROLL_POSITION_X, x);
        editor.putInt(SCROLL_POSITION_Y, y);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

and i restore it in `onCreate` like this:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        restoreScrollPosition();
    }

private void restoreScrollPosition() {
        SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int x = sp.getInt(SCROLL_POSITION_X, 0);
        int y = sp.getInt(SCROLL_POSITION_Y, 0);
        scrollView.post(() -> scrollView.scrollTo(x, y));
    }
```

Now this works good BUT it is not scrolling to the exakt same position as it was before. For example if I scroll all the way to the bottom and after restore that state it starts at maybe 1 or 2 items above the bottom. What is the issue here?

Comment: this is not an issue, this is correct. Now tell me what you want to achieve and when you want to restore the state

Comment: Okay, can you tell me why this is correct? I want to restore the screen to the same state as it was before. Example Activity A has the Scroll view. Activity B does other stuff. When i navigate from A to B the scroll position is saved (well even without navigating). Then when I navigate from B to A (Back button or whatever navigation). Activity A should look exactly like before. The scroll view should be at the exact same position as before

Comment: do one thing, before going to activity B just log the current save state in activity A, and also do the same while coming back from activity B to A. then chk wits wrong with the positions

Comment: Take a look -> https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334

Comment: @rguzman i do not have an recycler view but a scroll view because my ui needs extra space but it is known in the first layout pass.

Comment: @RajendraMahato I will do that and post back here:)